# Uncaught Error: Class 'PDO' not found

Tags: php, freebsd, nextcloud

I had a perfectly working installation, but needed to upgrade PHP 7.3 to 7.4 due to EOL.

Since then, I have an error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PDO' not found in /usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/DB/Connection.php:103
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/AppConfig.php(341): OC\DB\Connection->getQueryBuilder()
#1 /usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/AppConfig.php(109): OC\AppConfig->loadConfigValues()
#2 /usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/AppConfig.php(300): OC\AppConfig->getApps()
#3 /usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/legacy/OC_App.php(972): OC\AppConfig->getValues(false, 'installed_versi...')
#4 /usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Server.php(691): OC_App::getAppVersions()
#5 /usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/AppFramework/Utility/SimpleContainer.php(160): OC\Server->OC\{closure}(Object(OC\Server))
#6 /usr/local/www/nextcloud/3rdparty/pimple/pimple/src/Pimple/Container.php(118): OC\AppFramework\Utility\SimpleContainer->OC\AppFramework\Utility\{closure}(Object(Pimple\Container))
#7 /usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/AppFramework/Utility/SimpleContainer.php(127): Pimple\Container->offsetGet('OC\\Memcac in /usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/DB/Connection.php on line 103
```

However, module PDO **is** present and loaded :

```
php -m | grep -i pdo
PDO
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
```

Tried to reinstall the whole PHP stuff, with no success.

Note that all `occ` commands succeed.

My config:

- FreeBSD 13
- Nextcoud 23.0
- PHP 7.4

Comment: But is it present and loaded _for PHP CGI?_ (Or mod_php, or whichever you're using on the web server.) Often there are separate php.ini configurations for the PHP CLI, for PHP CGI, for Apache2 mod_php, for PHP-FPM...

Comment: I use php-fpm, and it loads OK
```

Comment: ```
php -i 
...
PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, odbc, pgsql, sqlite

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => mysqlnd 7.4.27
```

Comment: My point is that `php -i` is not PHP-FPM, it's PHP-CLI, with a different configuration. You need to check PHP-FPM itself.

Comment: FIrst, please do not [edit a question to declare “SOLVED” in the title](https://superuser.com/posts/1702172/revisions). A solved question on this site is indicated by posting your answer and checking it off as the solved answer. That said, what @user1686 states is 100% correct: Running `php -I` only reflects what PHP via the command line is aware of. The PHP that is run via the web sever via  `mod_php` or `PHP-FPM` or anything via the web server is 100% different. This mixup is a basic mistake many make. (1/2)

Comment: What you should’ve done is create a file in your web root called `info.php` with this in it `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then visit `info.php` via a web browser. When that page is loaded you will see all of the info about PHP running through the web server. Including “Loaded Configuration File” which should show you something like `/etc/php.ini`. _That_ is the PHP config file the web browser version of PHP is loading and that’s where you should make adjustments to set modules to be loaded. FWIW, while your solution was to upgrade to PHP 8.0, watch out: It is a very new release. Be careful. (2/2)

Answer (score 0):

Finally upgraded the whole PHP stuff to 8.0, it fixed the problem